# Call method inside iframe that holds a Cesium map

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I can normally call a method that is inside the html of an iframe using this approach:

```
document.getElementById("frame_id").contentWindow.method_in_frame();
```

I can also call methods outside the iframe using the parent approach:

```
onclick="parent.method_outside_frame();
```

But if my iframe is holding an instance of the Cesium map this does not work. Does cesium having something that stops this from happening? Is there a way to override it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. You need to change the default security on Cesium with this line:

```
viewer.infoBox.frame.sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-forms allow-scripts";
```

Then, if you are creating any methods in the Cesium popups you need to add the parent call which allows the button to reference back to the container level.:

```
onclick="parent.method_outside_frame();"
```

More details here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/Ba_88VXBMvI

Comment: Be careful turning off sandboxing in the iframe, particularly if you allow users to supply their own descriptions or HTML content for the InfoBox.  If you allow users to supply descriptions that will be shown in an un-sandboxed iframe, you open your site to [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and similar attacks.

Comment: I know this post is aging, but I'd be curious if you tested this in IE or Edge. I've been using the sandbox approach for a year or more and it works great in Chrome and Safari, but doesn't work in IE or Edge.