# CesiumJS infobox script not running

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cesiumjs, czml

So I am working on customizing a Cesium map by displaying markers in various positions based on JSON data fetched from another server. One of the things I want to do is to create an accordion-like div element to hold a list of strings that can be toggled on and off (to hide the data if it is too long).

However, Cesium refuses to run my  code inside the entity description. I have tested the code with a simple function:

```
html += "<small onclick='test();'>[\u2212]</small>";
...
html += "<script>function test() { console.log('bob'); }<\/script>";
jsonData.description = html;    // The Cesium CZML JSON entity
```

However, running the code throws a `function not defined` error in the console, even when I allow scripts to run via

```
mapViewer.infoBox.frame.sandbox = "allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-forms allow-scripts allow-top-navigation";
```

My question is this: is there something I am doing wrong here? I know Cesium loads the entity description HTML code in a sandboxed iframe, but I should be allowing scripts to run in the sandbox. I have also tried putting the `test()` function outside of the description, but I still run into the same error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What browser(s) are you using? Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094588/call-method-inside-iframe-that-holds-a-cesium-map, setting the sandbox allows me to run scripts in Chrome for Windows and Safari for macOS, but not IE or Edge on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not supported. There's a PR for this:
https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/5764

Hopefully it would be approved sometime soon.